# why python code doesnt work without print-functions

Tags: python

I have a code like

```
file=open("cd.txt","r")
x=[]
f=[]
def simpsons(x,f):
    for line in file:
        y=line.split()
        x.append(float(y[0]))
        f.append(float(y[1]))
    return(x,f)
print(simpsons(x,f))
```

the problem is when I dont write "print(simpsons(x,f))" it takes x and f as an empty array I didnt understand. Why print functions changes it ?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are saying.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? You don't just print in this statement, you also call the function `simpson()`. Also, `x` and `f` ARE empty array since you define them that way.

Comment: The print function doesn't change it, but rather the fact that you're actually calling `simpsons`.

Comment: I see now. I just put y=simpsons(x,f) (to call the function) and it worked without doing anything else.  I thought that just using return makes the code run without calling it later.Or I am also kind of suprised that the code worked without using y but by just calling it and assinging it just some random value (in this case y)

Comment: `return` simply tells python to exit the function after its been called. In fact, the function could be called millions of times and the return would happen millions of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the print function, all you are doing is defining the function and the lists will stay empty. You must call the function and return x and f in order for you to see their values.

You are essentially giving the computer instructions on how to do something, but you aren't telling it to go through those steps.

Comment: @user37487 Glad I could help! If you think mine was the best answer, please flag it as the answer. It allows me to better help other people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The print function have nothing to do with your problem :) ! The array you provide are defined empty: `x=[]; f=[]`. You just called your function in the print statement.

Also, You should not use your function like this `simpsons(x,f)` if you want to return `x` and `f`. You don't need to pass them to the function beforehand, the lists `x` and `f` will be create inside the function.

Finally, , using a context manager with the keyword `with` is also a good practice with file in python. This will deal with the closing of the file.

```
def simpsons(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            y = line.split()
            x.append(float(y[0]))
            f.append(float(y[1]))
    return x,f
x,f = simpsons('cd.txt')

print(x, f)
```

Comment: well thanks for your help